# when he was fouled

Tags: meaning, ellipsis, ambiguity

a. It wasn't only Tom who was furious when he was fouled. I was too.

b. Tom wasn't the only one who was furious when he was fouled. I was too.

Could those be used if the intended meaning is

Tom was furious when **he** was fouled and I was furious when **I** was fouled.
?

If the answer is 'yes', then we have ambiguity in the second sentence. Normally, it would mean that I was furious too when **he** was fouled.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences could technically be read in either way: that Tom was fouled and you were both furious, or that you both got fouled and were both furious indepentently.

However this ambiguity isn't much of an issue, because most speakers will contextually understand that a foul (in sport) happens to usually only one person at a time and that you're probably talking about a specific foul that was poor.

You'll find that this kind of ambiguity is used in some jokes, where the ambiguity is unlikely and unexpected, and therefore makes a funny punchline.